# Nginx caching symlinks

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cache, php7

I have a deployment system on my web server, every time an app is deployed it creates a new timestamped directory and symlinks "current" to the new directory. This all workded good and great on apache, but on the new nginx server I've set up, it looks like a script from the "old" deployment is being run instead of the new symlinked one.

I have read some tutorials and posts on how to resolve this but there is not much info and nothing seems to work. Here is my vhost file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<sname>.+?).testing.domain.com$;
    root /var/www/$sname/current/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
        add_header        Cache-Control public;
        add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
        expires           7d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and here is my fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this as at the moment every deployment involves deleting previous deployment. System is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS ; PHP 7.1 ; Nginx nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> [Embedded Variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables), `$realpath_root`: an absolute pathname corresponding to the [root](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) or [alias](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)
>   directive’s value for the current request, with all symbolic links
>   resolved to real paths

The solution of using `$realpath_root` instead of `$document_root` is copy-pasted all around the Q/A sites and forums; it is actually hard to avoid finding it.Yet, I've only seen it well **explained** once by [Rasmus Lerdorf](https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126#issuecomment-24020445). It's worth sharing as it describes *why* it works and *when* it should be used.

> So, when you deploy via something like Capistrano which does a symlink
>   swap on the document root, you want all new requests to get the new
>   files, but you don't want to screw over requests that are currently
>   executing as the deploy is happening. What you really need to create a
>   robust deploy environment is to have your web server be in charge of
>   this. The web server is the piece of the stack that understands when a
>   new request is starting. The opcode cache is too deep in the stack to
>   know or care about that.
>
> With nginx this is quite simple. Just add this to your config:
>
> ```
> fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
> fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
> ```
>
> This tells nginx to realpath resolve the docroot symlink meaning that
>   as far as your PHP application knows, the target of the symlink if the
>   real document_root. Now, once a request starts, nginx will resolve the
>   symlink as it stands at that point and for the duration of the request
>   it will use the same docroot directory, even if the symlink switch
>   happening mid-request. This entirely eliminates the symptoms described
>   here and it is the correct approach. This isn't something that can be
>   solved at the opcache level.

Kanishk Dudeja [had problems](https://medium.com/@kanishkdudeja/truly-atomic-deployments-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-aed8a8ac1cd9) with this and added a useful notice: make sure these changes will actually be in final configuration, i.e. after `include fastcgi_params;` which otherwise overrides them.

Comment: Hi, this is a great answer, but if you notice in my config I have fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; included after fastcgi_params, and this does not actually help. When i restart php-fpm the symlinks get resolved. Would this indicate that I have a php caching issue instead?

Comment: Revise. Your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` has `$document_root`, not `$realpath_root`.

Comment: Hmm... but `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set to `$realpath_root` so the way i understand it, it should chain pull the value or am I completely wrong and `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is not related to `$document_root`

Comment: No, the parameter `DOCUMENT_ROOT` doesn't change the variable `$document_root`. They only have the same name. From [FastCGI Example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/): "the `$document_root` variable is hardcoded and may not reflect your install (will cause variations on ‘script not found’ errors, usually). To use NGINX + Virtual Host + PHP you should ommit the `SCRIPT_NAME` variable in order for PHP to choose the correct `DOCUMENT_ROOT`."

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer and your explanation, my mistake was the assumption that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` affects `$document root`

Comment: I'm using Apache + php-fpm on the servers with this issue and clearing opcached on deploy worked for me, we have a bash script for deployment not Capistrano though. I think is a simpler solution and it's a good practice to clear your opcache on deploy anyway. Esa thanks for link to the Rasmus comment that's gold!

Answer (score 3):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157022/make-nginx-follow-symlinks, it seems you may be able to work around the issue by changing

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

to

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

(i.e. changing the path from `$document_root` to `$realpath_root`).

I don't have access to an nginx server at present to confirm this (my home server is currently undergoing a rebuild), but the solution seems to be collaborated by https://medium.com/@kanishkdudeja/truly-atomic-deployments-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-aed8a8ac1cd9.